# I am not able to find section tag when I an scraping data of dishes on zomato using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am not able to scrape section element using this please help me to fix this issue

```
def get_Zomato_menu():
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(zlink)
source = driver.page_source
soup = bs(source, "html.parser")
a = soup.find_all("section",attrs={"class": "sc-jqGTrP"})
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend **Scrapy** instead of Selenium/Splash; you need to tweak target website's headers and then it will allow you smooth access to all pages. I have fetched more than 10K records in a day using Scrapy.

As for Selenium, the reason why you are unable to locate the element is that, it's changing it's 'class' frequently. You need to locate the element using some reference point/element.